# Sort or Order by specific values with Elasticsearch 5

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

Trying to figure out how to sort elasticsearch results so that fields with specific values always show first.  In this case, I want specific SKUs to show first when showing category pages (I'm using bool query to generate elasticsearch results for category pages).

If I were trying to accomplish this with MySQL, I'd use the case statement:

```
ORDER BY CASE sku
    WHEN 'sku1' then 1 WHEN 'sku2' then 2 WHEN 'sku3' then 3 ELSE 4 END
```

This query executes:

```
{
    "sort" : [
        {
          "_script": {
            "type": "number",
            "script": {
                "inline" : "params.sortOrder.indexOf(doc['skuid_text'].value)",
                "params": {
                  "sortOrder": [
                    "SKUID1",
                    "SKUID2",
                    "SKUID3"
                  ]
                }           
            },
            "order": "asc"
          }
        }
    ],
    "query" :{
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {
                    "term" : {
                        "category_codes" : "CATEGORY1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But it's returning "-1" as the sort value for all records, eg:

```
sort": [
    -1
]
```

Note: 'skuid_text' is the SKU field I have analyzed as "keyword" type.  I have tried both doc['skuid_text'].value and doc['skuid_text']  And I have verified that SKUs in the "sortOrder" array are definitely included in the result set.

What am I missing?  Or, is there a completely different way to approach the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the original query DOES kind of work, it's just that the way I was ordering with "asc" was pushing all the skus in the sortOrder array to the end.

If you reverse the order of the skus in sortOrder and do some math on it, it will sort correctly.  Kind of hack-y though.  I'd love to know if there's a better way anyone can think of.

```
{
    "sort" : [
        {
          "_script": {
            "type": "number",
            "script": {
                "inline" : "(9999)-params.sortOrder.indexOf(doc['skuid_text'].value)",
                "params": {
                  "sortOrder": [
                    "SKUID3",
                    "SKUID2",
                    "SKUID1"
                  ]
                }           
            },
            "order": "asc"
          }
        }
    ],
    "query" :{
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {
                    "term" : {
                        "category_codes" : "CATEGORY1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This plugin did what you need for <5 versions.  You could give it a try on your installation as is, or see what the author has to say about a 5.x update.

https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-functionscore-conditionalboost